# Assignment of NaN in Pandas not sticking?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of values that are x, y, z values (Longitude, Latitude, Elevation).  I want to replace outliers with `nan` by scanning for bad values via a formula.  Everything works, except when I assign the value to the dataframe it resets to the original value.  Function of interest is:

```
def removeOutliers(dataframe, header):  
    for ii in range(len(dataframe['Lng'])):
        dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        df_copy = dataframe.copy()
        a = df_copy.iloc[ii]['Lng'] -  df_copy.iloc[:]['Lng']
        b = df_copy.iloc[ii]['Lat'] -  df_copy.iloc[:]['Lat']
        c = np.array((a**2 + b**2)**0.5   )    
        d = np.zeros((len(df_copy['Lng'])))
        e = np.zeros((len(df_copy['Lng'])))
        d[:] = df_copy.iloc[:]['Well']
        e[:] = df_copy.iloc[:][header]
        idx = np.argpartition(c, n_samples+1)
        max_loc = np.where(e[idx[0:n_samples+1]] == e[ii])
        neighbors = np.delete(e[idx[0:n_samples+1]], max_loc)
        avg = np.mean((neighbors))
        std = np.std(neighbors)
        if ii==148:
            print(df_copy.iloc[ii][header])        
        if df_copy.iloc[ii][header] > (avg + tolerance*std) or df_copy.iloc[ii][header] < (avg - tolerance*std):
            df_copy.loc[ii, header] = np.nan
        if ii==148:
            print(df_copy.iloc[ii][header])
            print(avg + tolerance*std)
            print(avg - tolerance*std)
    return df_copy    

new_data = removeOutliers(data_by_zone, 'elevation')
```

The goal is to find the 20 closest samples, calc the mean and std. dev, and if the reference sample is more than `avg+tolerance*std` (where tolerance=1.5 in this case) then replace with nan.
This prints:

```
5223
nan #this is how I know my if statement is working
372
277
```

I then run
print(new_data.iloc[148]['elevation'])

and I get

```
5223
```

So, it is like it is replacing it, but when I am assigning it to new_data it gets reset to original value.  How do I make the nan stick?  If it makes a difference it is python3.7 with pandas0.25.1. 
Note: I only set a copy of the dataframe to avoid the SettingWithCopy warning...

**Update:**
I have also tried using `df_copy.iloc[ii][header]` and `df_copy.iloc[ii, df_copy.columns.get_loc(header)] = np.nan`, but no luck

**Update 2** Issue was caused by having the dataframe inside the for loop.  Moving it to before the loop solved the issue.

Comment: theoretically - you show that you have ```5223``` and then just next is ```nan```. shouldn't you check el ```149``` instead?

Comment: This is a typo. Look in your if statement. You set `NaN` with **loc**. There's no guarantee that `df.loc[148]` is the same index as `df.iloc[148]`

Comment: @Gregorz `iloc[148]` is the one I am trying to replace... I print it before replace (get 5223) and print after replace (get nan), but then once the function assigns it to `new_data` it is back to 5223.